# How to read Secret Manager secrets as file (e.g. GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as Json)?

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, gcp-secret-manager

So far I would point `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to the file which stores the service-account (SA) credentials for the Firebase SA e.g. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/credentials.json`.

```java
@Value("${api-key.google.application-credentials}")
private String googleCredentials;


@Bean
public FirebaseApp firebaseApp() throws IOException {

    LOGGER.info("Initializing Firebase.");

    FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(googleCredentials);
    FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
            .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
            .build();

    if (FirebaseApp.getApps().isEmpty()) {
        return FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }

    return FirebaseApp.getApps().get(0);
}
```

Moving towards deployment, I've decided to go with GCPs Secret Manager.

I was wondering if I can read a secret-value "as file" such that the code above works with

```yaml
api-key:
  google:
    application-credentials: ${sm://GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
```

as well as

```yaml
api-key:
  google:
    application-credentials: ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:google-credentials.json}
```

or is there another way this should be done?

I know I have the option to just use the raw JSON and create a temporary file which I'd pass to `GoogleCredentials.fromStream()` but that's just weird. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where will be run your application? On Google Cloud or elsewhere?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's running under Cloud Run. I figured that it might work by setting the resource-id of a secret like `${sm://projects/project-id/secrets/GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}` once I manage to get the secret manager working

Comment: If you are under Cloud Run, you don't need a service account key file. It's a bad practice. You can use the Cloud Run runtime service account. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Am I getting this right? Basically I have to do nothing as the client libraries will automatically access these credentials as they run in the Cloud Run context?

Comment: Yes, it's the ADC (Application Defautl Credential) mechanism. On Google Cloud, there is always a metadata server that expose the credential of the current runtime environment. That's why, keys are useless because already loaded in the  service context

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Got it. Just re-deployed and so far no complaints except the thing about the [secret manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76064326/gcp-secret-manager-environment-variables-and-secrets-not-resolved-in-spring-boo?noredirect=1#comment134149679_76064326). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As per previous comment:

> When using Google Cloud Run, a service account key file is not needed. Client libraries will automatically access the credentials of the runtime environment because of the Application Default Credentials (ADC). Cloud Run has a metadata server that exposes the credential of the current runtime environment. Additional information can be found through this link on [Service Identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity).